# Kivy - [Critical] Warning too much iteration, when drawing Ellipse

Tags: user-interface, graphics, kivy

I have been struggling recently creating a filled `Circle` in Kivy that stays a circle when the window is re-sized to a different width or height. I looked at the question here:

[Centering an object in Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460965/centering-an-object-in-kivy)

But when I implement my `Circle` like so:

```
<BigCircle>
    width: min(self.size)
    height: min(self.size)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 0
        Ellipse:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

<MainScreen>:
    FloatLayout
        size: root.size
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size

        BigCircle:
            id: big_cir

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name="Main"))
        return sm
```

I get the error:

> [Critical][Clock   ]Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame. Check your     code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute

I am doing nothing with the `Clock`, but I am using a `ScreenManager`. Currently, `MainScreen` is the only screen. If I change the height/width to not include the `min()` then it works, but that is necessary to keep the `Circle` circular. Otherwise it becomes elongated when re-sized and looks bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have an infinite loop due to `BigCircle` `width` and `height` being adjusted based on its `size` (width, height). Try changing your `BigCircle` to:

```
<BigCircle>
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 0
        Ellipse:
            size: min(self.size), min(self.size)
            pos: root.center_x - min(self.size)/2, root.center_y - min(self.size)/2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess I'm still slightly confused since I thought inside the canvas `self.size` referenced the width/height array of the widget.